# Kernel security levels in ubuntu

Tags: security

Is there any ubuntu equivalent of BSD Kernel Security Level? If yes, how can one change the security level?

Comment: You mean *securelevel*s?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant *securelevel*, this is a *BSD kernel specific security mechanism. Linux (and therefore Ubuntu) does not have such a solution.

There is an *old* thread on this on [LKML](https://lkml.org/lkml/1998/4/6/12) by the way.

Comment: A more up to date discussion about this is at https://lwn.net/Articles/566169/